# Starting a sentence with of

Tags: sentence-starts

Can we start a sentence with 'of'. I have been working this poem and I am starting every sentence with of:

> "Of rotten eggs and gap-toothed grin.
>
> Of white lies and silly faces."

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: "Of this topic, I have little to criticize."  It does strike the ear as Yoda-speak.  But since it is poetry, you can get away with subtle things like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a subjective request for writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And if the OP hadn't given a reason for the question, you'd have complained about not having enough context.  This isn't a "subjective" request for advice on how to write poetry.  It's a question about an introductory prepositional phrase.

Comment: @deadrat: No it's not. It's a non-native speaker trying to write poetry in a language they're not familiar with, which I suggest is a mug's game.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "No it's not," he explained.  The OP may or may not be a non-native speaker; the OP may or may not be the world's worst poetaster.  But the one thing the OP is not is someone asking for advice on how to write poetry.  The OP has a question about the acceptability of starting a sentence with *of*.  The answer is one of *yes*, *no*, or *maybe*.  Notice that "You're a mug" is not on that list.

Comment: @deadrat: As cobaltduck points out, you can write whatever you like if it's "poetry". And DJClayworth says we're not even looking at *sentences* here (but we can see many "oddities" besides the "start sentence with a preposition" issue), so the idea of asking whether the text is "grammatical;" is just nonsense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And yet, DJC answers the question in a perfectly sensible manner, and BD give a beautiful example of the usage. Go figure. I submit that whatever "oddities" "we" see isn't germane.  The dismissive contempt for low-rep users, not so much.

Comment: What you have are not complete sentences but just prepositional phrases.  Perfectly legitimate for poetry (you did get your license renewed, right?) but not for ordinary prose.

Answer (score 2):

Of the grammatical errors you should worry about, starting a sentence with the word 'of' is not one. There are plenty of valid sentences like that, and the preceding sentence is an example. It's a simple reversal of the more normal sentence "Starting a sentence with the word 'of' is not one of the grammatical errors you should worry about." (To be clear, you shouldn't worry about it because it's not a grammatical error at all.)

I should point out that the lines you have written are not complete sentences, since they lack a verb. This only means that you need to repunctuate so that the sentence doesn't end at the end of the line, and the verb comes afterwards. For example (and with no pretensions of writing good poetry):

> Of rotten eggs and gap-toothed grin,
>
> of white lies and silly faces,
>
> this poem tells.

It's also true that lots of poetry sacrifices grammar to other considerations, so it may not be worth worrying about at all.

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site.  What's wrong with this answer?  Is it wrong about initial *of*'s.  (Hint: no)  Is it unclear? (See the first hint.)  Do need evidence?  (Hint: Go here -- https://books.google.com/books?id=oaX0AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT58&dq=%22of+all+the+things%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj87vuVjpbLAhVIbz4KHa1lB0kQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22of%20all%20the%20things%22&f=false  When you do this, you leave bad answers unimproved and give the impression that good answers are wrong.

Comment: Cf. [Ecclesiastes 12:12 (NRSV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+12%3A12&version=NRSV): "Of anything beyond these, my child, beware. Of making many books there is no end, and much study is a weariness of the flesh."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Oh, nice!  Divine, even.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer because "of" comes after a colon, but:       The time has come, the Walrus said,    
To talk of many things:     
 Of  shoes--and ships--and sealing-wax--  
 Of cabbages--and kings--    (Walrus and the Carpenter, Lewis Carroll)        ( PS I cancelled out the DBDV)